# Java program had compilation error yet ran successfully

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
class Return
{

      public static void main(String args[])
      {
         boolean t=true;
         System.out.println("Before the return");

         if(t)
         return;

         System.out.println("This wont execute");   
      }
}
```

This program is from Herbert Schidt. I tried to run this program using command prompt without if(t)
to see the compilation error

```
error: unreachable statement  
   System.out.println("Wont Execute");
```

I understood this error but program is running fine when i execute the command java Return.
It shows the output

Executes

So I wanted to know how this program is running even with compilation error?

Comment: Are you sure you're not running a class file that was there before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost certainly running the last successfully compiled version of this class. When you execute the java compiler, it doesn't erase its old output, it overwrites it. So if you compiled `Return.java` once successfully, you'll have a `Return.class` on your disk. If you alter `Return.java` to be uncompilable and try to compile it, the `Return.class` from the previous *successful* compile will still be there.

Comment: I closed everything and then again ran the program having the compilation error. It still executed fine

Comment: I guarantee you, if you have a compilation error *nothing* got compiled. You are running the class from the last time you successfully compiled it.

Comment: Ok. So does that mean until I get another successful compilation it will run the previously compiled program only?. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Just try to change the text in the first println(...) and check what is the output next time . (Hint: the previous text :) )